# Insert a lot of fields into a word document

Tags: vba, performance, ms-word

I have the following code:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
Set rng = Application.Selection.Range

For i = 0 To 25000
    ActiveDocument.Fields.Add rng, WdFieldType.wdFieldExpression, "1+2", False
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = true
```

Is there a way to further increase its performance?

(Noticed that if I would hide the application `Application.Visible = false` its faster but I don't really want do that)

(The amount is an edge case, but I would still like to make it plausible and currently, it's taking around 30 minutes to complete, which no user will wait)

Comment: This is off topic for SO, since you're trying to improve working code, it belongs on [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: It does belong on CR, but I'm not sure how much help they can give. There's not really much to improve on.

Comment: That might be true, @Riker, but it's got a better shot at getting help, now that it's been posted there.

Comment: You may want to delete this question now that it's been posted on CR